# How I got 50+ reputations for my answer

Tags: support, reputation

I got 50+ reputations for my answer but that question was not started bounty. Is there any options to give our reputations to some one who answered to my question.

This is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329132/android-custom-dropdown-popup-menu/21329225#21329225) which I answered

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such feature.

However, you can start a bounty on the question with reputation points and then then accepted answer will be given the bonus points.

Comment: But how I got +50 reputations for my answer? I added my answer link above.

Comment: @shylendra There was a bounty: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21329132/revisions

Comment: @Stijn Is he started bounty for that question which I answered?

Comment: @shylendra Yes, a user started a bounty with *Reward existing answer* as the reason and then chose your answer.